# How to bind parameters in query with influxdb-java

Tags: java, parameters, prepared-statement, influxdb

I am not able to bind parameters in this code:

```
import org.influxdb.InfluxDB;
import org.influxdb.InfluxDBFactory;
import org.influxdb.dto.BoundParameterQuery;
import org.influxdb.dto.Query;
import org.influxdb.dto.QueryResult;

public class BindTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InfluxDB influxDB = InfluxDBFactory.connect("http://127.0.0.1:8086");
        String s = "SELECT LAST(*) FROM batch_assembly_monitoring WHERE last_batch_start = $lbs";
        Query query = BoundParameterQuery.QueryBuilder.newQuery(s)
                .bind("lbs", 234567890)
                .create();
        System.out.println(query.getCommand());
        QueryResult result = influxDB.query(query);
    }
}
```

The output I get at stdout:

`SELECT LAST(*) FROM batch_assembly_monitoring WHERE last_batch_start = $lbs`

and also InfluxDB log contains this:

> [httpd] 172.17.0.1 - - [24/Sep/2020:12:40:29 +0000] "POST
> /query?params=%7B%22lbs%22%3A234567890%7D&q=SELECT+LAST%28%2A%29+FROM+batch_assembly_monitoring+WHERE+last_batch_start+%3D+%24lbs
> HTTP/1.1" 200 89 "-" "okhttp/4.8.1"
> 20fe610d-fe63-11ea-81ba-0242ac110002 271

It seems binding parameters are not bound and a placeholder string is used in query instead of value 234567890.

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was that I didn't set the database after connect:

```
influxDB.setDatabase("my_database");
```

After that it started working. InfluxDB log still does not contain bound parameter, only "lbs" string, but the parameter has been passed.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem. I couldn't find the data, but I could find the data when I manually replaced the parameters and executed sql.
`POST http://10.6.203.108:8086/query?db=unicom_power_test&q=select+*+from+cl_device_prop+where+equip_number+%3D+%24equipNumber+and+prop_key+%3D+%24propKey&params=%7B%22equipNumber%22%3A82%2C%22propKey%22%3A%22C40002%22%2C%22second%22%3A%222024-02-26T16%3A00%3A00Z%22%7D (0-byte body)`

Comment: I found the reason. The parameter I bound is of Integer type. In the spliced SQL, it is id=1, but in fact, the data can only be found when id='1'.